# Does anyone know how to do jenkins vsphere cloud plugin setup (configuration as code )

Tags: jenkins, plugins, vsphere, configuration-as-code

Today I started playing with the vsphere-cloud plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/vsphere-cloud-plugin/) and I am trying to add the vsphere cloud configuration to the clouds section of the helm chart.

```
  secretClaims: []
  # - name: secretName        # required
  #   path: testPath          # required
  #   type: kubernetes.io/tls # optional
  #   renew: 60               # optional

  # Name of default cloud configuration.
  cloudName: "kubernetes"
```

I found the key index after installing the plugin (
https://(jenkins-host)/configuration-as-code/reference#Cloud-vSphere), which gives the keys, but not the yaml layout.
Ideally, I would like to deploy the helm chart with  two clouds the default kubernetes one and an additional vsphere cloud.

Has anyone got this to work ?

I can sort of guess the keys from the config, but not sure what the yaml definistion would look like....

```
  secretClaims: []
  # - name: secretName        # required
  #   path: testPath          # required
  #   type: kubernetes.io/tls # optional
  #   renew: 60               # optional

  # Name of default cloud configuration.
  cloudName: "kubernetes"
  ...

  cloudName: "vsphere-test"
  ...
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/values.yaml#L327